# Why does Windows 10 think there is no internet when Acrylic DNS is enabled?

Tags: windows-10, dns

We have been using Acrylic DNS on our work computers for years to block access to unsafe things, advertising, and other things online. This has worked great for all the time we have used it, but now suddenly Windows 10 thinks there is no internet.

The settings are all set to the Acrylic DNS defaults, but something in one of the last Windows updates changed the way it handles what Acrylic DNS does and things have gotten confused.

To be clear, we do have internet, and the only applications that thinks we don't have internet seems to be Office applications. It isn't a big deal, except Outlook doesn't download the complete messages (just images I think) because it thinks there is no internet.

We have tried disabling all the firewalls, and that makes no difference.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, and were you able to come up with a solution?

Just in case you are unfamiliar with Acrylic DNS, it creates a local DNS server that allows you to blacklist and whitelist addresses. You point your DNS at Acrylic DNS at 127.0.0.1 for IPv4 and ::1 for IPv6, and then Acrylic DNS uses Googles Public DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

We are at a total loss here.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. A completely stock configuration of the latest AcrylicDNS causes Windows to report No internet access. This is false, but some apps (Google Drive for Desktop, Spotify) rely on this false reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Acrylic DNS developer Massimo contacted me back and suggested the following changes:

Start **regedit**, navigate to the following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\NetworkConnectivityStatusIndicator

Add a new REG_DWORD value

```
UseGlobalDns
```

assign it the value

```
1
```

After that, open **Services**, find **Network Location Awareness** service, open the properties, change the startup to **Automatic (Delayed Start)**